# javascript function sets the value of a form input field, but then the value disappeared

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to do a live database search using ajax with a form input field.
The whole thing runs so far that i can select a text from the proposed list.
The corresponding event "livesearchSelect" is also addressed, the value of the input field is set. Unfortunately the set value is missing in the form.
I have no clue what is going on, someone can throw some hints at me pls ?

**screenshot**

[image: the form with filled search and proposed list]

**html:**

```
<form name="demoform" id="demoform" action="" method="post"  >
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="a value"  class="form-control" >
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  class="form-control" >
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="search" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Live Search</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search" value=""  class="form-control"  oninput="livesearchResults(this, '/livesearch/Album');">
                <ul class="list-group" id="search-results" style="display:none">
                    <li class="list-group-item">?</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**javascript:**

```
function livesearchResults(src, dest){
    var results = document.getElementById(src.id + '-results');
    var searchVal = src.value;

    if(searchVal.length < 1){
        results.style.display='none';
        return;
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = dest + '/' + searchVal;
    // open function
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var text = xhr.responseText;
            results.style.display='inline';
            results.innerHTML = text;
            console.log('response from searchresults.php : ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}

function livesearchSelect(src) {
    var input_element = document.getElementById(src.parentElement.id.split("-")[0]);
    input_element.defaultValue = src.text;
    input_element.value = src.text;
}
```

**php controller:**

```
<?php

namespace controller;

use database\DBTable;

class livesearch extends BaseController {
    
    public function index() {
        echo "nothing here";
    }

    public function Album($input) {
        $table = new DBTable('Album');
        $results = $table->where('Title',$input.'%', 'like')->findColumnAll('Title', '', 6);

        foreach ($results as $key => $value) 
            echo '<a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="livesearchSelect(this);">'.$value.'</a>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Elements don't have `text` properties. Did you mean `input_element.value = src.textContent`

Comment: In this case src is the selected list item and the value to pass is either in src.text or as you said in src.textContent. In both cases the correct selected value is assigned to input_element.value. 
The value even pops up for a sec and then its reset by whatever.

Comment: Please convert the sample to a *complete* one, as per [guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that the dynamic hHTML is invalid: though the page implicitly expects search results to be a sequence of `<li>`, the PHP controller returns a sequence of `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking an [anchor element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) with an [`href` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href), even when blank, will [load the linked page](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:activation-behaviour), which is what you see happening here.

One solution would be to prevent the default action for the link (by e.g. returning `false` in the handler or calling [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)), but a better design would be to replace the `<a>` elements (which aren't actually links) with  something more semantically appropriate. Given that the consumer expects a sequence of `<li>`, the simplest solution is to replace the `<a>` in the PHP controller with `<li>`. The result would still have a higher degree of coupling than is desirable; the HTML classes and click handler couple the results tightly to the specific search form, rather than representing the resource as its own thing.

Not that `text` is not a DOM-standard property of HTML elements; you should be using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead.

Comment: The careless use of a href in the <a> element, even when left blank was the problem.  Just change the response of the controller to: `echo '<li class="dropdown-item" onclick="livesearchSelect(this);">'.$value.'</li>';` - thank you a lot for that usefull hint.